# Can't install vue cli

Tags: npm, vue.js

I'm trying to install the Vue Cli but I'm getting the following error:

```
$ npm install -g @vue/cli
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @vue/cli@latest
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Here's some of my environment info:

```
$ npm -v
6.1.0
$ node -v
v8.11.1
```

Comment: same command works for me. node v8.11.1 npm 5.6.0

Comment: Are you able to install other packages? Do you have a proxy or something that could prevent npm from working?

Comment: what is the URL you get with this command `npm get registry`
and let's see the output when you run `curl -v $URL -o /dev/null` - replace $URL with the one you got from previous command. e.g `curl -v https://registry.npmjs.org/ -o /dev/null`

Comment: @runwuf that was it thanks! I had it set to a private registry. Answer below and I'll accept it

Comment: @JohnnyMetz - glad you found the registry was the issue, answer posted below, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is the URL you get with this command `npm get registry` and let's see the output when you run `curl -v $URL -o /dev/null` - replace $URL with the one you got from previous command. e.g `curl -v https://registry.npmjs.org/ -o /dev/null`